# Proving a set is open (with the condition that $z \neq c$)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider some set $A=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : z \neq f(x,y)\}$, where $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous real-valued function and $X$  is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Would I be correct in saying that if $z \neq f(x,y)$ then this means that $z > f(x,y)$ or $z < f(x,y)$ which are both open and since the union of open sets is open $\implies z \neq f(x,y)$ is open thus showing that $A$ is open?

Comment: yes that's one way to do it, if you manage to show that those two sets you define are indeed open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, but incomplete. If you use that approach, then the set$$\{(x,t,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid z>f(x,y)\}\tag1$$is open because it is equal to $F^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)$ (with $F(x,y,z)=z-f(x,y)$), which is an open set, because $F$ is continuous (which follows from the continuity of $f$) and because $(0,\infty)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$. And the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid z<f(x,y)\}$ is open because it is equal to $F^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,0)\bigr)$, which is an open set, because $F$ is continuous and because $(-\infty,0)$ is an open subset of $(-\infty,0)$.

Of course, it would be simpler to say that $(1)$ is open because it is equal to  $F^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$ and because $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying all that!